# Atmega328p timer2 ctc won't fire

Tags: c++, timer, avr, arduino-uno

I'm attempting to configure timer 2 for CTC with a prescalar of 64. It is intended that it uses compare match A rather than compare match B.

This is the code that I use to set up the timer:

```cpp
uint8_t set_timer() {

        TCCR2A = (1 << WGM21);
        TCCR2B = (1 << CS22);
        TCNT2 = 0;
        OCR2A = 249;

        // Interrupt every ms
        TIMSK2 |= (1 << OCIE2B);

        return 1;
}
```

My understanding is that TIMSK is an interrupt mask for OCF2A and OCF2B, and masking OCIE2A enables interrupt compare match A request. Atmel studio says the exact opposite (it shows OCF2B set rather than OCF2A). However, the datasheet indicates that setting OCIE2A will enable OCF2A.

That being said, the interrupt never seems to fire. The ISR for the timer is labeled `TIMER2_COMPA_vect`. I have confirmed using avr-gcc -E that `TIMER2_COMPA_vect` gets changed to `__vector_7` by the preprocessor (which seems strange to me, because vector 7 is the watchdog, although changing the interrupt number doesn't seem to have any effect).

I can tell that the timer works. In addition, it appears as though the interrupt request is made. The interrupt just never actually happens. I do know that interrupts are enabled. Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm including the interrupt handler code.

```cpp
#include <avr/io.h>

__zero_reg__ = 1

.section    .bss
mod_four_count:
    .zero 1
reg_saver:
    .zero 1

.section    .text
    .global TIMER2_COMPA_vect

TIMER2_COMPA_vect:
    push    r31
    push    r30
    push    r29
    push    r28
    // Use this as the zero register
    push    r1
    clr r1
    // Load system time
    lds r28,system_time
    lds r29,system_time+1
    lds r30,system_time+2
    lds r31,system_time+3
    // Add one to 28,29
    adiw    r28,1
    // If overflow, then add one to 26
    adc r30,__zero_reg__
    // If overflow, then add one to 27
    adc r31,__zero_reg__
    // Store system time
    sts system_time,r28
    sts system_time+1,r29
    sts system_time+2,r30
    sts system_time+3,r31
    // Check to see system time % 4 == 0
    lds r28,mod_four_count
    cpi r28,3
    // If not, increment and store
    breq    reset_mod_four_count
    inc r28
    sts mod_four_count,r28
// Go through process of restoring registers and exiting
cleanup:
    pop r1
    pop r28
    pop r29
    pop r30
    pop r31
    reti
// Otherwise, reset counter and then set address of do_housekeeping
reset_mod_four_count:
    sts mod_four_count,__zero_reg__
    // Restore the remaining registers
    pop r1
    pop r28
    pop r29
    pop r30
    // Except use r31 to set return address
    pop r31
    sts reg_saver,r31
    ldi r31,lo8(gs(call_housekeeper))
    push    r31
    ldi r31,hi8(gs(call_housekeeper))
    push    r31
    lds r31,reg_saver
    reti
```

Comment: I don't see any interrupt handler code.   You say you have it but don't show it.  That could be why it "never actually happens."  Also why does this function return `int` and always return `1`?  And please don't bother with figuring out what vector it maps to.  If you follow the Atmel/Microchip app note, it will work.

Comment: @TomServo I don't think that the interrupt is not happening because I did not post it here. My issue is that the interrupt never gets called, even despite the flag going up. I figured that the content of the code itself was probably not relevant (aside from the name). As for the return value, I've just been prioritizing the interrupt handler since the return value has little function impact.

The "AVR130: Setup and Use of AVR Timers" seems to be the most relevant application note. I'll spend some time checking it out.

Comment: @TomServo I did consulted the Atmel app note as you had mentioned. Since I'm not doing anything asynchronous, there were only two different changes that I could make to the program: I cleared TIFR2 and I changed TIMER2_COMPA_vect to ISR_OCIE2A. Neither had any effect (ISR_OCIE2A wasn't even registered as a vector, so there wasn't any way it could be called in the case of an interrupt). 

The issue seems to be the same, which is that the timer ISR does not fire, even where there is a compare match. Is there a better place to ask this question? I haven't found anybody who seems to be able to.

Answer (score 0):

If the interrupt should be handled you have to enable interrupts globally:

```c
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

void set_timer() {
  // ...

  // Interrupt every ms
  // Here OCIE2B is enabled
  TIMSK2 |= (1<<OCIE2B);

  // Enable interrupts globally
  sei();
}
```

Also write the ISR even if there is no code

```c
// For Compare Match on Channel A
ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect)
{
  // ...
}

// For Compare Match on Channel B
ISR(TIMER2_COMPB_vect)
{
  // ...
}
```

In your case you will need `TIMER2_COMPB_vect`